# How can I draw a quiver plot with varying line thickness?

Tags: pgfplots

This question originates in [Scalar field in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51103/scalar-field-in-pgfplots/51160#comment106106_51160) .

How can I draw a quiver plot in which the arrows have the same length, but their line width varies according to some scalar property of the vectors?

Comment: @marko please note this answer to your feature request in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51103/scalar-field-in-pgfplots

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pgfplots allows to employ `point meta` as additional input coordinate. Typically, `point meta` is used as color data, but it can also be used for different purposes.

In this case, you can use it as line thickness parameter for a quiver plot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\U{1}
\def\V{2*x}
\def\LEN{(sqrt((\U)^2 + (\V)^2)}
\begin{axis}[axis equal]
    \addplot[blue,
        point meta={\LEN},
        quiver={
            u={(\U)/\LEN},v={(\V)/\LEN},
            scale arrows=2,
            every arrow/.append style={line width=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000 * 2pt},
        },
        -stealth,samples=15,
    ] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example defines some macros `\U`, `\V`, and `\LEN` where `\LEN` is the length of these vectors. Then, a quiver plot is drawn where each vector is normalized to unit length - and the length parameter is assigned as `point meta`. This is a simple and standard way of communicating extra data to plots (you could also input extra values in a table).

Finally, `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` is a scalar value in the range [0,1000] such that `0` corresponds to the *minimum* `point meta` value and `1000` corresponds to the *maximum* `point meta` value.

The expression for the `line width` scales this linearly such that the minimum line thickness is 0 and the maximum is 2pt.

Note that `axis equal` is necessary if we want to *see* that the vectors have the same sizes.