# Quiver plot with pgfplots: scale arrowheads with arrowsize

Tags: pgfplots, arrows

It is my understanding that the quiver plot with `pgfplots` keeps a constant arrowhead size, irrespective of the size (should I say length) of the arrow itself. Is there a way to have the arrowhead size linearly depending on the length of the arrow?

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[domain=-3:3, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[Couleur, quiver={u=-x, v={-y},scale arrows=0.085},-{Latex[width=2pt,length=3pt]},samples=21] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** A possible solution is given below but it is not really convincing because the arrowhead size is hard to control. Furthermore, the line thickness is almost zero in the center of the figure while arrowheads do not vanish.

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\def\U{-x}\def\V{-y}\def\LEN{(sqrt((\U)^2 + (\V)^2)}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[blue,point meta={\LEN},quiver={u={(\U)},v={(\V)},scale arrows=.15,every arrow/.append style={line width=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000 * .5pt}},- latex,samples=24] {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See [How can I draw a quiver plot with varying line thickness?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51441/how-can-i-draw-a-quiver-plot-with-varying-line-thickness) for a way of scaling the line width and arrowhead size of quiver plots.

Comment: @Jake Thanks. It looks like a duplicate then. I could not find it.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, since that answer also scales the width of the arrow line, not just the size of the head.

Comment: @Jake maybe I could use something in the line of `-{Latex[width=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*2pt,length=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*3pt]}` to scale the arrowhead only. I'll try later. Scaling the arrow line as well is fine with me.

Comment: What I said above does not seem to be working. I cannot really say why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approach suggested by @Jake is the right direction. Unfortunately, `-{Latex[width=...]}` causes strange problems when used insided of `every arrow`. It appears that this kind of arrow key reconfiguration is unsupported. I will look into it eventually, sounds like some incompatibility between the `arrows.meta` library and `pgfplots`.

But it works if you use `scale length` which appears to be better suited anyway:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-3:3, view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[blue,
    point meta={sqrt(x^2+y^2)},
    quiver={
        u=-x, 
        v={-y},
        scale arrows=0.085,
        every arrow/.append style={%
            -{Latex[scale length={max(0.1,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)}]},
        },
    },
    samples=21,
] 
    {0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea as such is similar to that of [How can I draw a quiver plot with varying line thickness?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51441/how-can-i-draw-a-quiver-plot-with-varying-line-thickness) : we define `point meta` to resemble the vector length. Then we scale `every arrow` by `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000`. Keep in mind that `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` is a number in the range [0,1000]; it is the result of mapping the value of `point meta` into that range. Since `scale length=0` is illegal, we have to introduce a lower limit here.

Comment: ok thanks: it looks promising. One comment: the arrow in the middle "should" disappear. I guess it is impossible to achieve because of the illegal `scale length=0`.

Comment: I see. What if you use `0.01` as smallest possible scale? It looks like a dot...

Comment: Will you keep us posted when you update `pgfplots` (if you do)? Thanks

Comment: @pluton I suppose the next update will be at the end of 2014.

Comment: This seems only to "flatten" the arrowheads; I.e. the scaling is not uniform...arrows are scaled only in the direction parallel to the arrow. Is that intended? Is it possible to scale uniformly?

Comment: @mrc I may be able to look into it eventually, but I suggest that you file a new question.