# Quiver plot with scaled arrowheads

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208620/quiver-plot-with-pgfplots-scale-arrowheads-with-arrowsize).

Here is a MWE showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5.167in,
height=3.622in,
at={(0.867in,0.489in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.45,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot[%
point meta={sqrt((\thisrow{u})^2+(\thisrow{v})^2)},
quiver={u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v},
every arrow/.append style={-{Straight Barb[scale length={max(0.01,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)},scale width={0.5*max(0.01,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)}]}}}
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
%
x   y   u   v\\
0   0   0.45    0.45\\
1   0   -0.45   0.45\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image: Output of MWE]
The problem is that the arrowheads are extremely small!

Comment: Change `max(0.01, ... ` to `max(10, ...`

Comment: Thanks @Jake that does work. So since both vectors are the same length `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` defaults to 0?

Comment: It looks like adding `point meta min=0` makes sure that `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` isn't 0 when the arrow length is non-zero. To get reasonable sized arrows I still need to add a scaling factor on the computed length though.

Comment: In your real code (I assume this is just a simplified example), do you want the arrowheads to all have the same size, or do they depend on the vector length?

Comment: Yes this is just a simplified example. I would like them to have a size proportional to the vector length, similar to the default output of MATLAB's quiver function.