# Axis plotting and soccer field scale

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code and works for me

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{inimigo.dat}
x   y   label
520 100 a0
30  410 a1
510 520 a2
220 620 a3
360 320 a4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{pontofixo.dat}
x y label
1150 450 Gol
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{inicial.dat}
x   y   label
340 0   g0
340.789 421.1   g1
340.904 374.027 g2
394.844 448.825 g3
404.386 327.304 g4
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 paperwidth=25cm,
 left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1200,ymin=0,ymax=900, xstep=1,ystep=1,nodes     near coords,enlargelimits=0.0]

\xdef\DoLater{}

 \addplot +[only marks,mark=*,nodes near
 coords={\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at (\myx,\myy);}\labelz}, 
 visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
           table{pontofixo.dat}; % this defines the coordinate (Goal)
           % if I do not define it, the next sequence will throw an error
\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
nodes near coords={\labelz\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at
(\myx,\myy);
\xdef\DoLater{\DoLater,\labelz}
}}, visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
            table{inimigo.dat};

\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
nodes near coords={\labelz\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at
(\myx,\myy);
%\xdef\DoLater{\DoLater,\labelz}
}}, visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
            table{inicial.dat};

 \end{axis}
 \foreach \Point in \DoLater{
\ifx\Point\empty%
\relax
\else
\draw (\Point) -- (Gol);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This code generate this figure:
[image]

I need something similar to this, I made the code below but it seems to me that I can not hit the scales ... and how do I remove the box around the labels and numbers?

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
 \usepackage{geometry}

 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{inimigo.dat}
x   y   label
520 100 a0
30  410 a1
510 520 a2
220 620 a3
360 320 a4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{pontofixo.dat}
x y label
1150 450 Gol
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{inicial.dat}
x   y   label
340 0   g0
340.789 421.1   g1
340.904 374.027 g2
394.844 448.825 g3
404.386 327.304 g4
\end{filecontents*}


\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\tikzset{
   every node/.style={draw=white, very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0},
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
}

\newcommand\area[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}, transform shape, rotate=#2]
 \node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
 \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{axis}[x=.01cm, y=.01cm, xmin=0,  ymin=0, xmax=1200,ymax=900, nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0] %, xmin=0,xmax=1200,ymin=0,ymax=900, xstep=2,ystep=2, nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0]
\xdef\DoLater{}

 \addplot +[only marks,mark=*,nodes near coords={\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at (\myx,\myy);}\labelz}, 
 visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
           table{pontofixo.dat}; % this defines the coordinate (Goal)
           % if I do not define it, the next sequence will throw an error
\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
nodes near coords={\labelz\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at
(\myx,\myy);
\xdef\DoLater{\DoLater,\labelz}
}}, visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
            table{inimigo.dat};

\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
nodes near coords={\labelz\makebox[0pt]{\coordinate(\labelz) at
(\myx,\myy);
}}, visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{x}\as\myx},
 visualization depends on={value \thisrow{y}\as\myy}] 
            table{inicial.dat};

 \end{axis}
 \foreach \Point in \DoLater{
  \ifx\Point\empty%
  \relax
  \else
  \draw[black,thick,dashed] (\Point) -- (Gol);
  \fi
 }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I feel responsible because I created the first code. Even though it works, it can be simplified quite a bit using [this cool answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799). And then I undid the styles needed for the soccer field just before the plots start.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikzducks}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
 \usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            name=#1-\coordindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{inimigo.dat}
x   y   label
520 100 a0
30  410 a1
510 520 a2
220 620 a3
360 320 a4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{pontofixo.dat}
x y label
1150 450 Gol
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{inicial.dat}
x   y   label
340 0   g0
340.789 421.1   g1
340.904 374.027 g2
394.844 448.825 g3
404.386 327.304 g4
\end{filecontents*}


\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\tikzset{
   every node/.style={very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0,draw=white}, 
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
}

\newcommand\area[2]{
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},transform shape, rotate=#2]
 \node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
 \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}
\tikzset{ % <- undo the settings needed for the soccer field
   every node/.style={}, 
   every path/.style={},
}

\begin{axis}[x=.01cm, y=.01cm, xmin=0,  ymin=0, xmax=1200,ymax=900, 
nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0] %, xmin=0,xmax=1200,ymin=0,ymax=900, xstep=2,ystep=2, nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0]

 \addplot +[only marks,name nodes near coords=Gol,
 mark=*,nodes near coords={\labelz}, 
 visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},
 ] 
           table{pontofixo.dat}; % this defines the coordinate (Goal)
           % if I do not define it, the next sequence will throw an error
\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
name nodes near coords=a,
nodes near coords={\labelz}, 
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz}] 
            table{inimigo.dat};

\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
name nodes near coords=g,
nodes near coords={\labelz}, 
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz}] 
            table{inicial.dat};

 \end{axis}
 \foreach \n in {0,...,4}
 {
 \draw[black,thick,dashed] (a-\n.south) -- (Gol-0.south);
 \draw[black,thick,dashed] (g-\n.south) -- (Gol-0.south);
 }

%  % activate this for the ducks
%  \definecolor{blueinter}{RGB}{0,102,170}%
%  \foreach \n in {0,...,4}
%  {
%  \node at (a-\n.north){\tikz[xscale=-1,scale=0.4]{\duck[signpost={\scriptsize \color{black} \rotatebox{40}{\n}}, signback=white,
%  tshirt=black,stripes={\stripes[color=white]},football]}};
%  \node at (g-\n.north){\tikz[xscale=-1,scale=0.4]{\duck[signpost={\scriptsize \rotatebox{40}{\n}}, signback=blueinter,
%  tshirt=black,stripes={\stripes[color=blueinter]},football]}};
%  }
\draw[very thick,white] (contour.north west) rectangle (contour.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you may improve the result tremendously by using @samcarter's tikzducks and @CarLaTeX's advice, i.e. add `\usepackage{tikzducks}` to the preamble and uncomment

```
  % activate this for the ducks
  \definecolor{blueinter}{RGB}{0,102,170}%
  \foreach \n in {0,...,4}
  {
  \node at (a-\n.north){\tikz[xscale=-1,scale=0.4]{\duck[signpost={\scriptsize \color{black} \rotatebox{40}{\n}}, signback=white,
  tshirt=black,stripes={\stripes[color=white]},football]}};
  \node at (g-\n.north){\tikz[xscale=-1,scale=0.4]{\duck[signpost={\scriptsize \rotatebox{40}{\n}}, signback=blueinter,
  tshirt=black,stripes={\stripes[color=blueinter]},football]}};
  }
```

to the very end:
[image]

**EDIT**: And here comes a code for the players.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikzducks}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc,backgrounds}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
 \usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            name=#1-\coordindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{inimigo.dat}
x   y   label
520 100 a0
30  410 a1
510 520 a2
220 620 a3
360 320 a4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{pontofixo.dat}
x y label
1150 450 Gol
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{inicial.dat}
x   y   label
340 0   g0
340.789 421.1   g1
340.904 374.027 g2
394.844 448.825 g3
404.386 327.304 g4
\end{filecontents*}


\definecolor{field}{RGB}{0,156,0}

\tikzset{
   every node/.style={very thick, inner sep=0, outer sep=0,draw=white}, 
   every path/.style={draw=white, very thick},
}

\newcommand\area[2]{
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},transform shape, rotate=#2]
 \node[minimum width=.55cm,minimum height=1.832cm, anchor=west] (small#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=1.65cm,minimum height=4.032cm, anchor=west] (big#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[minimum width=.244cm, minimum height=.732cm, anchor=east] (goal#2) at (0,0) {};
 \node[inner sep=.3mm, circle, fill=white] (penalty#2) at (1.1,0) {};
 \begin{scope}
    \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
    \clip (big#2.south east) rectangle ++ (1,5); 
    \draw[white, very thick] (penalty#2) circle (0.915cm);
    \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 }


\newcommand{\Player}[1]{
\ifcase#1
\xdef\ColorList{pink,green,pink,pink} %0
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,green,pink,pink} %1
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,green,pink,green} %2
\or
\xdef\ColorList{pink,green,pink,green} %3
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,pink,green,pink} %4
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,pink,green,green} %5
\or
\xdef\ColorList{pink,pink,green,green} %6
\or
\xdef\ColorList{pink,pink,green,green} %7
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,green,green,green} %8
\or
\xdef\ColorList{pink,pink,pink,pink} %9
\or
\xdef\ColorList{pink,green,green,pink} %10
\or
\xdef\ColorList{green,pink,pink,green} %11
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,1.2);
\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle (0.5);
\foreach \Color [count=\n] in \ColorList
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Angle}{70+80*\n}
\draw[fill=\Color] (\Angle:1.1) circle (0.4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[field] (-1,-1) rectangle (13,10);
\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=9cm] (contour) at (6,4.5) {};

% Center
\draw (contour.north) -- (contour.south);
\draw (contour.center) circle (0.915cm);
\fill[white] (contour.center) circle (.5mm);

% Areas
\area{contour.west}{0}
\area{contour.east}{180}

% Corners
\foreach \corner [count=\xi starting from 0] in {south west, south east, north east, north west}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={90*\xi:(contour.\corner)}]
        \draw ([xshift=1mm]contour.\corner) arc (0:90:1mm);
    \end{scope}
}
\end{scope}
\tikzset{ % <- undo the settings needed for the soccer field
   every node/.style={}, 
   every path/.style={},
}

\begin{axis}[x=.01cm, y=.01cm, xmin=0,  ymin=0, xmax=1200,ymax=900, 
nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0] %, xmin=0,xmax=1200,ymin=0,ymax=900, xstep=2,ystep=2, nodes near coords,enlargelimits=0.0]

 \addplot +[only marks,name nodes near coords=Gol,nodes near coords={}] 
           table{pontofixo.dat}; % this defines the coordinate (Goal)
           % if I do not define it, the next sequence will throw an error
\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
name nodes near coords=a,nodes near coords={}] 
            table{inimigo.dat};

\addplot +[scatter/position=relative,only marks,mark=*,
name nodes near coords=g,nodes near coords={}] 
            table{inicial.dat};

 \end{axis}
 \foreach \n in {0,...,4}
 {
 \draw[black,thick,dashed] (a-\n.south) -- (Gol-0.south);
 \draw[black,thick,dashed] (g-\n.south) -- (Gol-0.south);
 }

\draw[very thick,white] (contour.north west) rectangle (contour.south east);

 \foreach \n in {0,...,4}
 {
 \node at (a-\n.south){\Player{\n}};
 \node at (g-\n.south){\Player{\n}};
 }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX You were too fast, but you could tell me which trikots they should wear ;-)

Comment: LOL, wonderful! If you want to represent the derby _egreg vs CarLaTeX_, you should do Juventus vs Inter :)

Comment: @marmot and @CarlasTex! Many thanks for the response and for the fun.

But only one doubt: did I hit the scale? I'm not quite sure ... comparing the two figures ..

Comment: @samcarter, no one is winning, I am researching mechanisms for blocking plays in soccer games, but the search is at the beginning yet. Figure is just a way to represent players and positions.

Comment: @MarcosLaureano Sounds like a really interesting topic!

Comment: @marmot FYI: The problem with the rotation of text for left facing ducks should now be fixed in the development version https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks.sty

Comment: @MarcosLaureano What do you mean by "did I hit the scale"? Could you please try to describe the problem a bit more?

Comment: @marmot, this lengh field is 12cm x 9cm, my matriz is 1200x900 and I use 0.1cm for scale in axis... Did I calculate that right? will the points in my array (enemy.dat for example) be correctly represented?

Comment: @MarcosLaureano Ahh, now I seem to start to understand what you mean. But to me it looks good, the coordinates are where they should be, and you put for instance the Gol node at (1150,450), which should be just a bit left of the Milano goal, and it is. Or do you have an example of something that doesn't seem right?

Comment: @marmot No ... it was just a doubt, a little lack of confidence ...;) I tikz I'm very newbie! Another question, in the place of the ducks is it possible to use another figure to represent the points, such as this one that I will upload? each figure represents a player (by number).

Comment: @MarcosLaureano Sure, one can replace the ducks by anything. Just to make sure I understand you correctly (Google's translation to marmot language is still very poor ;-)): the number (between 0 and 4) sets the number of small circles in the bigger contour?

Comment: @marmot, Yes twelve possible combinations ... change only central blue circle for a yellow circle (see figure).

Comment: @marmot, You are my hero!!! ;)

Comment: @marmot but is possible the figure show exactly in coord position? Because the labels (a0..an, g0..gn) would no longer be necessary and the figure would replace the point.

Comment: @MarcosLaureano I updated my answer.